# How can I use python's subprocess.Popen with a single input csv and one row per process being input?

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, concurrency, subprocess

I would like to run multiple instances of a python script while inputting the variables to a class instantiation in each script as one row of a csv per instance.

For example, in the main file I'm opening the csv and storing as a list with each row being a list of strings. I want to iterate over the list of list of strings, and feed each list of strings as the input to subprocess.Popen().

Each process should be running asynchronously, with a class instantiation for each that have taken in different variables.

I've found example code for subprocess.Popen() and this is a non-working modification of it I'm trying to use:

```
with open('variables.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    input_variables = list(reader)

for iv in input_variables:
    proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'script_to_run.py', iv, '{}_out.csv'.format(iv[0])])
    procs.append(proc)

for proc in procs:
    proc.wait()
```

input_variables is a list of list of strings, and iv is a list of strings.

The main point I'm lost on, is how to pass in each list of strings to be used in each process? Is the 3rd paramater (I've currently got set as 'iv') required to be a csv?

If that's the case and I'm trying to create 100 asynchronous processes, does that mean that I need 100 input csvs with a single row of strings each? That doesn't seem to make sense.